# How to rewrite matrix formula for Diagonalizable matrix $A=PDP^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, diagonalization

I am working on an old exam containing a question about Diagonalizable matrix, I am quite confident about the subject overall but there is one simple thing that bothers me, a lot!

We are given the formula $A=PDP^{-1}$ I know from my memory that this can be rewritten as $D=P^{-1}AP$ to solve for D, but I cannot find out how to do it. I have watched a few examples on Wikipedia and in some PDF file that hinted me in the correct direction.

What I believe,
For example:

$A=PD$ can be rewritten as $AP^{-1}=D$ if this was regular variables, but they are not, they are matrices, and with matrices, you can only put the "latest" number in front of the equation like this:

$A=PD$ can be rewritten as $P^{-1}A=P^{-1}PD=D$ this works fine but with the formula $A=PDP^{-1}$ I get stuck in an infinite loop of moving things in front of the equation and everything becomes a mess. There is clearly something easy I have missed out. Here are my calculations:

$A=PDP^{-1}$

$P^{-1}A=P^{-1}PDP^{-1}$

$P^{-1}A=DP^{-1}$

Now I want to get rid of $P^{-1}$ from the right-hand side but since I can only but things in front of D, everything gets messy and I get stuck in a never-ending loop of making things more complicated and adding $PP^{-1}=I$ to the equation hoping it would help but it doesn't :(

Comment: Right-multiply the equation $P^{-1}A=DP^{-1}$ by $P$,$$P^{-1}AP=DP^{-1}P=D$$Since matrix products don't commute in general, you can either pre-multiply or left-multiply a matrix $X$ with another matrix $Y$, as in $XY$, or you can do post-multiplication or right-multiplication, as in $YX$.

Comment: So you actually are looking for $P$ which will transform $A$ into a diagonal form, right?

Comment: @denklo Looking for D, but exact values are not needed, I know how to do that, I do not know how to rewrite matrix equations

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Okay so the trick is that I can multiply in front as I have done, or at the end of the equation?

Comment: That's correct, @J.Doe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to take into account that matrix multiplication is *not* commutative.

So from $A=PDP^{-1}$, just multiply with $P^{-1}$ *on the left*, and with $P$ *on the right*. As matrix multiplication is associative, you obtain
$$P^{-1}AP=P^{-1}(PDP^{-1})P=(P^{-1}P)D(P^{-1}P)=D.$$

Answer (score 1):

> I know from my memory that this can be rewritten as $D=P^{-1}AP$ to solve for D, but I cannot find out how to do it.

We start with the identity $A=PDP^{-1}$.

Begin by multiplying both sides on the left by $P^{-1}$ and then on the right by $P$, then make use of the properties that

- For any invertible matrix $A$, $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I$.
- For all square matrices $A$, we have $AI=IA=A$.
- Matrix multiplication is associative, i.e. $ABC = (AB)C = A(BC)$, where the multiplicative is assumed to be defined for the matrices $A,B,C$.

So, we obtain,

$$\begin{align}
A=PDP^{-1} &\iff P^{-1}AP=P^{-1}PDP^{-1}P \\
&\iff P^{-1}AP=(P^{-1}P)D(P^{-1}P) = IDI = D
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$P^{-1}AP = D$$

Comment: Nice thing about this result is that it's not exclusive to matrices at all. As invertible matrices form a Abelian Group over addition and Group over multiplication we see this results holds for all structures that have those properties!